# How do I use "IGNORE" in a database query?

Tags: 7, database

I would like to run a query similar to `INSERT IGNORE INTO the_table (nid, language) VALUES (8, 'Chinese')`, but I cannot find any documentation on how the "IGNORE" statement works with the Drupal DB API.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

```
db_merge('the_table')
  ->key(array('nid' => 8, language' => Chinese))
  ->fields(array(
      'nid' => 8,
      'language' => Chinese,
  ))
  ->updateExcept('nid','language')
  ->execute();
```

Would the code above be the equivalent of my initial query ?

**EDIT:** updateExcept method doesn't exist, no idea why it s still in the documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is a MERGE query with no UPDATE part. Something like this should work:

```
db_merge('the_table')
  ->key(array(
      'nid' => 8,
      'language' => Chinese,
  ))
  ->insertFields(array(
    'nid' => 8,
    'language' => Chinese,
  ));
  ->execute();
```

Comment: yes, thank you damien, i got that figured out already. Though in the docs the update method doesn t seem to exist at all ..

Answer (score 1):

db_insert() does not support `IGNORE` because this is not SQL standard but a mysql-specific extension. db_merge() is not what you want I think, because it either INSERTS or UPDATEs a row. There are two possible ways to work around this:

- You can simply use db_query() and pass a query string to it. However, this means that your code/module only works with MySQL and can not be used with PostgreSQL. This might be OK for a custom module for a specific site, but I would nevertheless strongly recommend to chose option 2 below. For a contributed module, this is wrong, obviously.
- The only clean way out of this is that you first need to check if such a row already exists with a normal SELECT query and if not, execute a normal INSERT query. Note that this method might be prone to concurrency issues, if two requests happen at the same time. You could work around that with a transaction and blocking write access to that table, but this might on the other hand slow down performance...

Comment: Thanks for you imput Berdir, though i was trying to avoid making a DB check as you mention in #2. But it s uneccesary perfectionism i guess. I got it working using damien method though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using IGNORE, I think you'll be interested to [`db_merge()`](http://drupal.org/node/310085), which adds or updates your data according to the query you execute.

Comment: Thanks Yvan though i can't seem to really figure out how to rewrite my query using db_merge, would you have an exemple to show me ?

Comment: After investigation DB_merge doesn't seem to be the way to go..